# And operator in MongoDB to perform query with multi-filters using the official .NET driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDB 3.2 and I want to make a query from C# using the official .NET [driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) (2.6)

Use Robomongo to perform the search, and the correct query is:

```
db.getCollection('collection1').find({ $and: [ { type: "ws128" }, { tsend: { $gte: ISODate("2018-05-11T14:39:33.000Z"), $lt: ISODate("2018-05-11T14:39:40.000Z") } }  ] })
```

I want to find all the documents that have the key **type = ws128** and that the variable **tsend is between the two dates** that are shown in the query.

In C #, I have the filters defined as shown below but I do not know how to do the query:

```
DateTime datetimestart =  new DateTime(2018, 5, 11, 14, 39, 33);
DateTime datetimeend =  new DateTime(2018, 5, 11, 14, 39, 40);
var filter1 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("type", "ws128");
var filter2 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gte("tsend", datetimeend);
var filter3 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Lt("tsend", datetimestart);
```

With a single filter, the search performed without problems as shown below, but I do not know how to include the 3 filters.

```
var cursor = collection.Find(filter1).ToCursor();
```

Can someone guide me to continue?
Thank you!
regards,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
collection.Find(filter1 & filter2 & filter3)
```

or alternatively:

```
collection.Find(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.And(filter1, filter2, filter3))
```

Answer (score 7):

use a single &

```
DateTime datetimestart =  new DateTime(2018, 5, 11, 14, 39, 33);
DateTime datetimeend =  new DateTime(2018, 5, 11, 14, 39, 40);
var filter1 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("type", "ws128");
var filter2 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gte("tsend", datetimeend);
var filter3 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Lt("tsend", datetimestart);
var andFilter = filter1 & filter2 & filter3;

var cursor = collection.Find(andFilter).ToCursor();
```

I would probably write that code a little differently. I find it easier to read and write:

```
DateTime datetimestart =  new DateTime(2018, 5, 11, 14, 39, 33);
DateTime datetimeend =  new DateTime(2018, 5, 11, 14, 39, 40);

var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter1 = builder.Eq("type", "ws128");
var filter2 = builder.Gte("tsend", datetimeend);
var filter3 = builder.Lt("tsend", datetimestart);

var cursor = collection.Find(filter1 & filter2 & filter3).ToCursor();
```